# File size limit in multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, multer

I am accepting file of different types such as images and videos. I want to handle different sizes for image and video type. I want images of max size 10mb and videos of 100mb. I want to achieve this functionality with one multer instance.

```
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";
import { TEMP_DIRECTORY_PATH } from "../constants.js";
import { ApiError } from "../utils/ApiError.js";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, TEMP_DIRECTORY_PATH);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const fileName = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
        const fileExtension = path.extname(file.originalname);
        cb(null, fileName + fileExtension);
    },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    const imageMimeTypes = [
        "image/png",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/webp",
        "image/svg+xml",
    ];
    const videoMimeTypes = ["video/mp4", "video/webm"];

    const allowedMimeTypesForFields = {
        avatar: imageMimeTypes,
        coverImage: imageMimeTypes,
        videoFile: videoMimeTypes,
        thumbnail: imageMimeTypes,
        featuredImage: imageMimeTypes,
    };

    const allowedMimeTypesForField = allowedMimeTypesForFields[file.fieldname];

    if (!allowedMimeTypesForField) {
        return cb(
            new ApiError(
                500,
                `Invalid field ${file.fieldname}. Please ensure you are uploading to a valid field.`
            ),
            false
        );
    }

    if (allowedMimeTypesForField.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(
            new ApiError(
                400,
                `Invalid file type for ${file.fieldname}. Allowed file types for ${file.fieldname} are ${allowedMimeTypesForField.map((type) => type.split("/")[1]).join(", ")}.`
            ),
            false
        );
    }
};

export const upload = multer({
    storage,
    fileFilter, 
});
```

Is it possible to do this with my given code. Or I have to make 2 multer instances one for image and one for video.